# Divide-and-Conquer Exercise

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer

I need help on this question:
Given a sorted array of distinct integers A[1, . . . , n], you want to find out whether there is an index i for which A[i] = i. Give a divide-and-conquer algorithm that runs in time O(log n).

How I can proceed?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Where did you get stuck there?

Comment: I I tried using a modification of binary search. I don't think is the right way.

Comment: Why not? Binary search is a perfectly good way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Define $B[i] = A[i] - i$. What can you say about the array $B$? Use the fact that $A$ contains *distinct* integers.